# How can I edit rendering parameters programatically?

Tags: presentation, components, rendering-parameters

I have a rendering that is used on pages all over my site, and I had to add a new field to the Rendering Parameters it uses. I now need to update this field on a huge number of renderings, but only on renderings that exist within a particular placeholder, so I can't just apply it globally in standard values.

I've started writing a script to update the rendering parameters, and I think I've got the code to retrieve and modify the rendering parameters, but I'm not sure how to apply it back to the rendering and save it.

```
var testPage = db.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Home/Magazine/Issues/2009/August");
var renderings = testPage.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);

foreach (var rendering in renderings)
{
    var placeholderId = rendering.Placeholder;

    // check renderingitem id
    if (rendering.RenderingItem.ID == new Sitecore.Data.ID("{93F07F46-F356-419A-B937-A5EB2A9D63DD}"))
    {

        if (placeholderId == "/content-body/secondary-column-left")
        {

            var parameterString = rendering.RenderingItem.Parameters;
            var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(parameterString);
            parameters["Display Subtitle"] = "1";
            parameterString = parameters.ToString();

            // HOW DO I PUT THIS BACK ON THE RENDERING NOW?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Got the answer, here is the complete code. In my case I'm updating the `Display Subtitle` field but you can change this field or make the field name a variable if you want to:

```
public void SetRenderingParameterValue(
    Item item)
{
    using (new SecurityDisabler())
    {
        string defaultDeviceId = "{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}";
        string dynamicContentListingRenderingId = "{93F07F46-F356-419A-B937-A5EB2A9D63DD}";

        var layoutField = new LayoutField(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField]);
        var layoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
        var deviceDefinition = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(defaultDeviceId);
        foreach (RenderingDefinition rendering in deviceDefinition.Renderings)
        {
            var datasource = rendering.Datasource;
            var placeholderId = rendering.Placeholder;

            if (placeholderId == "/content-body/secondary-column-left")
            {
                if (rendering != null && rendering.ItemID == dynamicContentListingRenderingId)
                {
                    var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(rendering.Parameters);
                    parameters.Remove("Display Subtitle");
                    parameters["Display Subtitle"] = "1";
                    var newParams = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parameters.ToString());
                    rendering.Parameters = newParams;
                }
            }
        }
        item.Editing.BeginEdit();
        item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField] = layoutDefinition.ToXml();
        item.Editing.EndEdit();

    }
}
```

The `defaultDeviceId` is the ID of /sitecore/layout/Devices/Default (or whatever Device your rendering is on)

`dynamicContentListingRenderingId` is the ID of my rendering item under `/sitecore/layout/Renderings`

Comment: In some cases it's better to replace
var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(rendering.Parameters);
with
var parameters = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(rendering.Parameters);

ParseQueryString return nulls if parameters are stored without values (which is sometimes the case, for example with default unchecked checkbox in rendering params). ParseUrlParameters will return such parameter.

Answer (score 6):

I've not completely test this using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions, but it should get you pretty close.

```bsh
$item = Get-Item -Path "master" -ID "{961563FC-3445-4558-BF3A-06DF06BA6298}"
$renderingItemId = "{93F07F46-F356-419A-B937-A5EB2A9D63DD}"
$placeholderId = "/content-body/secondary-column-left"

# Accepts Hashtable, Ordered Dictionaries, etc.
$parameters = [ordered]@{"Display Subtitle"="1"}
Get-Rendering -Item $item -FinalLayout |
    Where-Object { $_.Placeholder -eq $placeholderId -and $_.ItemID -eq $renderingItemId } |
    Set-RenderingParameter -Parameter $parameters | 
    Set-Rendering -Item $item -FinalLayout
```